# Visualforce => Contacts are not fetching,what am I doing wrong here?

Tags: visualforce

Please help me out to solve this issue.I am struggling since a week.Now I think just one bit is missing from the issue. I have done everything but it seems contacts are failing to show.I will be glad if you share some time and help.I will appreicate it.

**controller**

```
public with sharing class DisplayAccWithContact1 {

   public contact con{get;set;}
   

    public DisplayAccWithContact1(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    
    con=new contact();

    }


    public String getContact() {
        return null;
    }

    public String accName {get;set;}

    List<Account> lstacc = new List<Account>();
    List<contact> lstcon = new List<contact>();
    public List<contact> getContacts() {
       lstcon.clear();
       accIds.clear();
       lstacc.clear();      
       lstacc=[select id,name from Account where name=:con.accountid];
       for(Integer i=0;i<lstacc.size();i++)
       {
           accIds.add(lstacc[i].Id);
       }
       
        lstcon =[select id,name,Phone, email,accountId from contact where accountid in : accIds];
        //system.debug('### List of Contacts for Test is ###'+ lstcon);
        return lstcon;
    }
    
    set<string> accIds = new set<string>();
    public pagereference showContacts() {
       return null;        
    }
}
```

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Contact" sidebar="false" extensions="DisplayAccWithContact1">
    <apex:form >      
        <apex:inputfield value="{!con.accountid}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="ShowContacts" action="{!showContacts}" rerender="out" status="mystatus"/><br/>
        
        <apex:actionstatus id="mystatus" starttext="please wait contacts are loading.......">
            <apex:facet name="stop">
                <apex:outputpanel id="out">
                    <apex:pageBlock >
                        <apex:pageBlockSection >
                            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Contacts}" var="c" rendered="{!con.accountid !=null}">
                                <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                                    {!c.Name}
                                </apex:column>
                                <apex:column headerValue="Phone">
                                    {!c.Phone}
                                </apex:column>
                                <apex:column headerValue="Email">
                                    {!c.Email}
                                </apex:column>
                            </apex:pageBlockTable>
                        </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    </apex:pageBlock>
                </apex:outputpanel>
            </apex:facet>
        </apex:actionstatus>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: showContacts returns null? Is the button pointing at the right method?

Comment: @Girbot I am not sure.

Comment: @cropredy Please do have  a look.

Comment: I would think that your button should be using "getContacts" not "showContacts".

Comment: I believe the problem is you are trying to match name to id, which is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is you are trying to match name to id, which is wrong.

Instead match Id to Id:

```
public List<contact> getContacts() {
    return [SELECT Name, Phone, Email FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :con.accountid];
}
```

Update: standard controller is redundant here.

This is the was how this can be refactored

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" controller="DisplayAccWithContact1">
    <apex:form >      
        <apex:inputfield value="{!con.accountid}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="ShowContacts" action="{!showContacts}" rerender="out" status="mystatus"/><br/>
        
        <apex:actionstatus id="mystatus" starttext="please wait contacts are loading.......">
            <apex:facet name="stop">
                <apex:outputpanel id="out">
                    <apex:pageBlock >
                        <apex:pageBlockSection >
                            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Contacts}" var="c" rendered="{!con.accountid !=null}">
                                <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                                    {!c.Name}
                                </apex:column>
                                <apex:column headerValue="Phone">
                                    {!c.Phone}
                                </apex:column>
                                <apex:column headerValue="Email">
                                    {!c.Email}
                                </apex:column>
                            </apex:pageBlockTable>
                        </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    </apex:pageBlock>
                </apex:outputpanel>
            </apex:facet>
        </apex:actionstatus>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public with sharing class DisplayAccWithContact1 {
    public Contact con{get;set;}
    public DisplayAccWithContact1() {
        con=new contact();
    }
    public List<Contact> contacts {get; set;}
    
    public PageReference showContacts() {
        contacts = [SELECT Name, Phone, Email FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :con.accountid];
        return null;        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.I appreciate it a lot. But I am still unsure where to make changes suggested by you. Can you please let me know exactly where do I make changes? I am just a week old in VF so! its all confusing and overwhelming.

Comment: replace the code of getContacts method with the code I provided

Comment: actually do you need standardController here?

Comment: I am not quite sure! I thought for lookup, to leverage contact.accountId I needed it. But what are your thoughts?Std controller wasnt needed at all? I would really appreciate your insights.

Comment: I have updated the answer to include code

Comment: You are THE best!!! Its working. Finally. Do you have any blogs or linkedIn so that I can follow you? You are a saviour!

Comment: yes, my blog is patlatus.wordpress.com

Comment: Thanks a lot! Adding to bookmark.